# How do I include quotation marks in a print statement if I am using a variable

Tags: python, variables, printing

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
word_length = len(word)

print("The length of", word,"is ", word_length)
```

If word is `'back'`, the output will be:

```
The length of back is 4
```

I want the output to be:

```
The length of 'back' is 4
```

Comment: `'The length of "{}" is {}'.fomrat(word, word_length)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Good way:

The best way is to use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
print("The length of '{}' is {}".format(word, word_length))
```

### The Bad way:

Using C-like statement, note that this is de-emphasised, (but not officially *deprecated* yet)

```
print("The length of '%s' is %s" % (word, word_length))
```

### The Ugly way:

One way is to have your string add with a `'` and using [`sep` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print)

```
print("The length of '", word,"' is ", word_length, sep = '')
```

Comment: While the Python documentation recommends using the newer `format` method, the older `printf`-style formatting has never been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repr` of a word to include the Python quotation marks (as they appear in e.g. the interactive interpreter); this has the added benefit of working reasonably when quotes are already in the string:

```
print("The length of", repr(word), "is", word_length)
```